# Language code for Flemish

Tags: android, localization, internationalization, android-resources

I would like to provide support for the Flemish language in my Android app, but as per [ISO 639-1](http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php) there is no separate code for this language. How can I then do this?

Comment: Maybe this can helps you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20527164/setting-application-locale-to-pt-br-programmatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using nl-rBE (dutch as used in Belgium) worked for me.

(`r` is required per the [Android localization reference](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources#LocaleQualifier)--the `r` denotes "region".)

http://www.localeplanet.com/icu/nl-BE/index.html

Comment: I'm curious, what does the "r" denote in your language tag?  Surely it should be "nl-BE"?

Comment: The "r" in the resource qualifier `nl-rBE` denotes "region".

Answer (score 3):

Bear in mind that the resource qualifier can combine language and country. Although Dutch and Flemish are both ISO 639-1 `nl`, you can attach a region qualifier as well to further specify the region.

The documentation [provides an example for British English](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html#strategies):

> Also, you might not need to create alternative text for every string. For example, assume the following:
>
> - Your application's default language is American English. Every string that the application uses is defined, using American English spellings, in `res/values/strings.xml`.
> - For a few important phrases, you want to provide British English spelling. You want these alternative strings to be used when your application runs on a device in the United Kingdom.
>
> To do this, you could create a small file called `res/values-en-rGB/strings.xml` that includes only the strings that should be different when the application runs in the U.K.

Similarly, you could provide this for Flemish by specifying the resource directory `values-nl-rBE`.

Answer (score 1):

If the language got no code, then you got rather no other way to "hijack" the code of other language or write own localization engine (or use something existing, but not the framework's one). As for hijacking the existing code, simply pick up that one that your user are most unlikely to face in real life and put your translation there.