# Different initial string files

Tags: android, string

is there any way to use different string files? I know that I can create files for another languages, but I want to load different files for English, depending on some initial value. It will be good if I could have one more file with default value. It is possible?

Comment: may be you can use different region codes.[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20527164/setting-application-locale-to-pt-br-programmatically]

Comment: I tried. It will be fine if I could create my own regions.

Comment: what I meant is to change the region fakely depend on your initial values.

Answer (score 1):

Android string resources are optimized for supporting different locales and you can force app to use particular locale. If you want use custom dictionaries for one language I would recommend to use custom class that will read string-array resources. Imho nice example is: Dirty Phrasebook

[Few articles about this app](https://blog.stylingandroid.com/), 
[Source code](https://bitbucket.org/StylingAndroid/dirty-phrasebook)

Comment: It's ok, but it isn't comfortable option in my project, but...I think It is the only way to do this.

Comment: It's Android :P. Allows many things apart from standard ones but it doesn't mean that will help with those :)