# Text to Speech(TTS) - Android - Portuguese

Tags: android, audio, android-studio, text-to-speech

I'm trying to reproduce some text with an android aplication that will help visually impaired people, most especially with TTS, but in my case I need Portuguese-Brazil speaking, and the TTS class does not have Portuguese available as locale. Does anyone have any idea how to implement a Portuguese Brazil reader?

I'm using Android Studio, and MinSDK is 15.

```
...

tts = new TextToSpeech (this, this);

tts.setLanguage(Locale.[X]);

...

tts.speak("Muito obrigado a todos!", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);

...
```

Comment: See my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20527164/setting-application-locale-to-pt-br-programmatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! My problem was that on the device was not installed TTS. So, just installed it from the google store(https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.tts&hl=en).

Answer (score 1):

How did you make your `onInitListener()`? When you call `tts = new TextToSpeech (this, this);` `onInitListener()` will connect TextToSpeech service to your `tts` instance. So, if you try to set language or speak sound, check this value:

```
tts = new TextToSpeech (this, this);

@Override
public void onInit(int status) {
    if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
        int res = tts.setLanguage(Locale.[X]);
        if (res >= TextToSpeech.LANG_AVAILABLE) {
            // Then, you can speak with your locale.
            // Call speak() in here or after this method.
            tts.speak("Muito obrigado a todos!", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
        }
    }
}
```